# What type of object does the latest ember-data store.filter return?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the past if I would use the filter func it would return an Ember.A([]) w/ my objects

```
var day = this.store.filter('day', function(model){
    return model.get('day_of_week') === 1;
});
```

So I could do something like this ...

```
var interval = day.objectAt(0).get('interval');
```

But w/ the latest master (as of today anyway) this doesn't return an object as I'd expect. Did the api change or did it somehow change what type is returned?

Answer (score 0):

`store.filter` Should return a promise array: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

You are likely attempting to access an object prior to the query resolving. You could refactor your code to be:

```
this.store.filter('day', function(model){
  return model.get('day_of_week') === 1;
}).then(function(days){ //Wait for the promise to resolve
  var interval = days.objectAt(0).get('interval');
  //do some more stuff now that you have your filtered day
});
```